# Can we conclude that $G_1 \not ≅ G_2$?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working in the following graph theory excercise:

> Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two graphs with $V(G_1) = {u_1, v_1, w_1, x_1, y_1, z_1}$ and $V(G_2) = {u_2 , v2_ , w_2 , x_2 , y_2 , z_2}$. If $v_1$ has degree $3$ and is adjacent to a vertex of degree $2$, while $v_2$ has degree $3$ and is not adjacent to a vertex of degree $2$. Can we conclude that $G_1 \not ≅ G_2$? Explain your answer.

What I think about the answer is that obviously because of adjacent vertices to $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not the same then $G_1 \not ≅ G_2$ but I'm not sure about it to be so obvious, thanks in advance for any critic to my solution, a hint or help.

Comment: Can you go even further and say because the vertices have different names then the graphs are different? If not then what role do the vertex names play in the question?

Comment: $\not\equiv$ is not $\neq$. Clearly $G_1\neq G_2$ because they (presumably) aren't defined on the same vertices. However, it's still possible that $G_1\equiv G_2$.

Comment: What does $G_1\equiv G_2$ mean??

Comment: Do you mean isomorphic?? The usual symbol for isomorphism is $\cong$. If you're going to use your own notation, it would be a good idea to define it, so we will know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following graph on 6 vertices.

```
A-----B
|     |
|     |
C-----D
 \   /
  \ /
   E
   |
   |
   F
```

Notice that vertices $A$ and $B$ have degree $2$, vertices $C$, $D$, and $E$ have degree $3$, and vertex $F$ has degree $1$. Vertices $C$ and $D$ are each adjacent to a vertex with degree $2$, but vertex $E$ is not adjacent to any vertex with degree $2$.

Can you use this to generate two isomorphic graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ with all the properties in the question?